# JSF Data table not displaying any data

Tags: java, css, jsf, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I have been messing around with some tutorial files I had and tried changing a data table that would normally just display a bunch of nonsense into a table that displays flower information form. I thought the changes would be pretty topical (just switching variable names for whatever I put in the database) but it seems as though I am missing something important. Some help or direction on the matter would be appreciated.

Instead of a table, the output I keep getting is this (literally this string)

Flower ID #{f.flowerID} Name #{f.name} Color #{f.color} Country #{f.country} Price #{f.price}

as opposed to the nicely formatted table from the tutorial.
[image: as opposed to the nicely formatted table from the tutorial]

Here are all my project files. I can't seem to find any error logs though.

ViewFlowers.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Flowers ABOUND</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h1>FLOWERS GALORE</h1>

        <h:dataTable value="#{flower.getFlowerList()}" var="f"
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >

        <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        Flower ID
                </f:facet>
                        #{f.flowerID}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        Name
                        </f:facet>
                        #{f.name}
        </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        Color
                        </f:facet>
                        #{f.color}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        Country
                        </f:facet>
                        #{f.country}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        Price
                        </f:facet>
                        #{f.price}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

FlowerBean.java

```
import jsf.Flower;

@ManagedBean(name="flower")
@RequestScoped
public class FlowerBean implements Serializable{
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of FlowerBean
     */

    DataSource ds;

    public FlowerBean() {

        //resource injection
//  @Resource(name="jdbc/flower")

//  if resource injection is not support, you still can get it manually.
            try {
                    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                    ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc:mysql://localhost/flow");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    //connect to DB and get customer list
    public List<Flower> getFlowerList() throws SQLException{

        if(ds==null)
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

        //get database connection
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();

        if(con==null)
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");

        PreparedStatement ps 
            = con.prepareStatement(
               "select flower_id, flower_name, flower_color, "
                                   + "flower_country, flower_price from customer"); 

        //get customer data from database
        ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();

                List<Flower> list = new ArrayList<Flower>();

        while(result.next()){
            Flower flow = new Flower();

                        flow.setFlowerID(result.getLong("flower_flowerid"));
                        flow.setName(result.getString("flower_name"));
            flow.setColor(result.getString("flower_color"));
                        flow.setCountry(result.getString("flower_country"));
                        flow.setPrice(result.getDouble("flower_price"));

            //store all data into a List
            list.add(flow);
        }
        return list;
        }
}
```

Flower.java

```
package jsf;

public class Flower {
    public long flowerID;
    public String name;
    public String color;
    public String country;
    public double price;

    public long getFlowerID() {
        return flowerID;
    }

    public void setFlowerID(long flowerID) {
        this.flowerID = flowerID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

table-style.css

```
.order-table{   
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.order-table-header{
    text-align:center;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5E5E5;
    border-bottom:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    padding:16px;
}

.order-table-odd-row{
    text-align:center;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFFF;
    border-top:1px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.order-table-even-row{
    text-align:center;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
    border-top:1px solid #BBBBBB;
}
```

Comment: Your JSF XML namespaces point to JSF 2.2 (compare to the ones in the tutorial). Are you on Glassfish 4 and which Mojarra version do you use?

Comment: It seems that JSF is not rendering your EL expressions , do you have necessary configuration in web.xml . See here for example http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar kind of a problem.

While creating the dynamic web project, I did not set **Java Server Faces v2.2 Project** in the Configuration. This is required to download java server faces capabilities in your project. Check below image with settings highlighted in yellow. Configure the settings according to the version you are using.

[image]